# Why the model is not displayed in the center of screen?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I want to show a point cloud with VTK. I inherit a class named VTKWidget from **QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget**, its constructor is that：

```
VTKWidget::VTKWidget(QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget* parent)
    :QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget(parent)
{
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget::defaultFormat());
    _renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
    _render = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    _actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    _points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    _mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    _polyData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();    
    _verts = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

    _polyData->SetPoints(_points);
    _polyData->SetVerts(_verts);

    _mapper->SetInputData(_polyData);

    _actor->SetMapper(_mapper);
    _actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    _actor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(2.0f);

    _render->AddActor(_actor);
    double color[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
    _render->SetBackground(color);

    _renderWindow->AddRenderer(_render);
    //setRenderWindow(_renderWindow);
}
```

Points will be modified in the function **updateData**, the **updateData** function is that:

```
void VTKWidget::updateData(const QVector<QVector<QVector3D>>& data)
{
    setRenderWindow(_renderWindow);
    _points->Reset();
    long long w = data.size();
    long long h = data[0].size();
    _points->SetNumberOfPoints(w * h);
    _polyData->Reset();
    _verts->Reset();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[0].size(); ++j)
        {
            vtkIdType pid;
            pid = _points->InsertNextPoint(data[i][j].x(), data[i][j].y(), data[i][j].z());
            _verts->InsertNextCell(1, &pid);
        }
    }
    _polyData->Modified();
    _mapper->Update();
}
```

The question is that if the code **setRenderWindow (_renderWindow);** is in the constructor, the point cloud will not show in the center of this widget, but will be if the code is in the function **updateData**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the whole point cloud at the end of `updateData`, you should use `_renderer->ResetCamera()`.
(https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderer.html#ae8055043e676defbbacff6f1ea65ad1e)

The fact that the location of `setRenderWindow()` impact the rendering is a side effect.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me to solve this problem

Comment: Then you probably want to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers